# "callback" argument must be a function Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm getting this error on "callback", this is the only part of the code where I use it. Thanks.

```
throw new TypeError('"callback" argument must be a function');
```

Error and code: https://pastebin.com/tbfdMdEK

Thank you!

Comment: try this `client.chatMessage(steamID, Config.options.successMessage, callback);`

Comment: Somewhere you are supposed to be passing a function for a callback, but you are either not passing that argument at all or you are passing something that is not a function.  We'd have to see a lot more code to know where that error is.  Typically, you would start at the exact source line of the exception and work up the call stack until you find a line of your code that is passing the wrong arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the following line you should probably pass a reference to `callback` instead of calling it.

Instead of this:

```
client.chatMessage(steamID, Config.options.successMessage, callback());
```

Do this:

```
client.chatMessage(steamID, Config.options.successMessage, callback);
```