# Decryption is not working in node (file-encryptor)

Tags: node.js, encryption

I am trying to encrypt files while uploading them and decrypt them when downloading using node.I managed to encrypt files successfully by using **file-encyptor module** , but when i try to decrypt files it gives me an error as below.

[image]

I tried many ways to resolve this and couldn't find an answer.If anyone can explain why this is happening and resolve this it would be really helpfull.Thank you!...

```
var express = require('express');
var _router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
let key = 'MySuperSecretKey';
var File = require('../models/fileSchema');                                                    
var encryptor = require('file-encryptor');
var options = { algorithm: 'aes256' };

var store = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:function(req,file,cb){
        var dir = `./uploads/files/${req.body.nic}/myFiles`;
        if(!fs.existsSync(dir)){
            fs.mkdirSync(dir , { recursive: true });
          }
        cb(null, dir);
    },
    filename:function(req,file,cb){
        const ext = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];                                                  
        console.log(ext);
        cb(null, Date.now()+'.'+file.originalname);
    }
});


var upload = multer({storage:store}).single('file');

_router.post('/upload', function(req,res,next){ // Where i upload files and encrypt them
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err){
            return res.status(501).json({error:err});
        }
        addFileToDb(req,res);
        var input = req.file.path;
        console.log('Input',input)
        input = path.resolve(input);
        console.log('Input',input)
        var output = input;
        encryptor.encryptFile(input, output, key,options, function(err) {
            if (err)
              throw err;
     console.log("Successfully Encrypted!");

});
        return res.json({originalname:req.file.originalname, uploadname:req.file.filename});
    });
});

function addFileToDb(req,res){
    var theFile = new File({
        file: req.file.path,
        creation_dt: Date.now()
      });
      theFile.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('ERROR!');
        }
    });
}

_router.post('/download', function(req,res,next){ // Where i want to downlode files and decrypt them
    filepath = path.join(__dirname,`../uploads/files/${req.body.nic}/myFiles`) +'/'+ req.body.filename;
    var input = `uploads\\files\\${req.body.nic}\\myFiles` +'\\'+ req.body.filename;
    input = path.resolve(input);
    var output = input;
    encryptor.decryptFile(input, output, key,options, function(err) {
                if (err){
                  throw err;}
         console.log("Successfully Decrypted!");

});
    res.sendFile(filepath);
});

module.exports = _router;
```

Comment: try [this callback thingy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44856183/4648586), basically, put that error handling function somewhere (you can assign a function to a variable in js), and then call the `decryptFile` this way: `encryptor.decryptFile(input, output, key,options, my_function)`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].